# Weak derivative as an $L^2$ limit of the difference quotient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that
$$\left\| \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h} - u' \right\|_2 \to 0\quad \text{ as } h \to 0, $$
where $u' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the weak derivative of $u$. In other words, the weak derivative can be written as an $L^2$ limit of a difference quotient.

We know that functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ are differentiable almost everywhere, so that the pointwise limit
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h} $$
exists and is equal to $u'(x)$ almost everywhere.

I would like to take the limit inside the integral (using dominated convergence), but I'm not positive that there is a dominating function... Does anybody have any hints, or an outright solution?

Note: This is the first exercise from Chapter 7 of Renardy & Roger's *An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*. I am not doing it for homework. Just for "fun."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, then in particular it's absolutely continuous, so that the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
$$
|u(x+h)-u(x)|\leq \int_0^1 |u'(x+th)||h|dt
$$
So that squaring and integrating over $\mathbb{R}$ we get (using Jensen's inequality and Fubini's theorem)
$$
\left\|\frac{u(\cdot +h)-u(\cdot)}{h}\right\|_2^2 \leq \| \int_0^1 u'(\cdot+th)dt\|_2^2 \leq \| u'\|_2^2, \quad \forall h>0.
$$
Now, since for smooth compactly supported functions the limit is clear, we pick $u\in H^1$ and $u_k\in C_c^\infty$ with $u_k\to u$ in $H^1$. Then we get
$$
\left\|\frac{u(\cdot +h)-u(\cdot)}{h}-u'(\cdot)\right\|_2 \leq \left\|\frac{u(\cdot +h)-u(\cdot)}{h} - \frac{u_k(\cdot +h)-u_k(\cdot)}{h}\right\|_2 + \left\|\frac{u_k(\cdot +h)-u_k(\cdot)}{h}-u_k'(\cdot)\right\|_2 + \| u'-u_k'\|_2
$$
The first term is bounded by $\| u'-u_k'\|_2$ by the previous inequality; the second term goes to zero since $u_k\in C_c^\infty$ so that we can make the LHS arbitrarily small for appropriate $k$ and $h$ small enough.

Comment: So the fundamental theorem of calculus holds once the weak derivative is integrable, right?

Comment: @JohnZHANG: That's right, at least in 1 dimension, in two or higher dimensions you get the fundamental thm of calculus on a.e. line.