# Differentiation in $L^p$ and Weak Differentiation.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, weak-derivatives

In Weiss and Stein's book on Fourier analysis in Euclidean spaces, they define the notion of a 'derivative in $L^p$'. To be precise, they define the difference operators

$$ (\Delta_h f)(x) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} $$

and say that $f$ has a derivative $g$ in $L^p(\mathbf{R}^n)$ if $\Delta_h f \to g$ in the $L^p$ norm as $h \to 0$. I haven't encountered this definition before. It seems it should be equivalent to some kind of weak differentiation, or at least related in some sense? However, I'm unable to find other references that talk about this kind of construction using the language that Stein and Weiss use. Is there another name for this notion, and how is it related to weak differentiation?

Comment: This is usually called strong derivative and there is  nothing weak about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 372-373 from this [lecture note](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/weak-derivatives.pdf), the relation between the weak derivative (in the distributional sense) and this *strong derivative* (as the limit in $L^p$ of difference quotient) is discussed.

For dimension $n=1$ and $p=2$, there's a [relatively easy proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000731/weak-derivative-as-an-l2-limit-of-the-difference-quotient?noredirect=1&lq=1) that the limit of the difference quotient converges to the weak derivative.